# How do I pass a js var to a django view

Tags: javascript, python, django

It's my first time working with JS, and I don't know how to pass a selected row in a table to my django's view file.

This is my HTML and my JS:

```js
var tabela = document.getElementById("minhaTabela");
var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
    var linha = linhas[i];
  linha.addEventListener("click", function(){

        selLinha(this, true); 
    });
}


function selLinha(linha, multiplos){
    if(!multiplos){
    var linhas = linha.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
      var linha_ = linhas[i];
      linha_.classList.remove("selecionado");
    }
  }
  linha.classList.toggle("selecionado");
}


var btnVisualizar = document.getElementById("visualizarDados");

btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var selecionados = tabela.getElementsByClassName("selecionado");
  //Verificar se eestá selecionado
  if(selecionados.length < 1){
    alert("Selecione pelo menos uma linha");
    return false;
  }

  var dados = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < selecionados.length; i++){
    var selecionado = selecionados[i];
    selecionado = selecionado.getElementsByTagName("td");
    dados += "CNPJ: " + selecionado[0].innerHTML + " - RAZÃO SOCIAL: " + selecionado[1].innerHTML + " - NOME FANTASIA: " + selecionado[2].innerHTML + "\n";
  }

  alert(dados);
});
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/banco.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<button id="visualizarDados">Visualizar Dados</button>

<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="minhaTabela">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>CNPJ</th>
      <th>RazaoSocial</th>
      <th>NomeFantasia</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>00000000000</td>
      <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxx S/A</td>
      <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>111111111111</td>
      <td>yyyyyyyyyyyy S/A</td>
      <td>yyyyyyyyyyyyyy</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script  src="{% static 'js/banco.js' %}" async> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of showing an alert, I would like to get this submit this var to my django's view. I have no idea how to do a form in this situation, because the table is generated by pandas.to_html, so I don't know how to insert a form inside this table to send the rows selected's column[0], column[1] and column[2]

Answer (score 1):

Note that Javascript is executed by the browser, while Django is run a server. In order to enable communication, you will have to use XHR, aka "Ajax".

On the JS side, you can create a HTTP request

using the fetch API (async/Promise)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

or with an XMLHttpRequest (synchronous)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

You should transform your variable to JSON and create a POST request to your Server

```
const URL = http://yourServer.local/yourController
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
      JSON.stringify(dados)
    }).then(result => {
       //what to do when the POST was successful and a possible answer was retrived
    })
```

on the Django end, please refer to the documentation on how to create a minimal controller and route to process a POST request
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/